# servlet set cookie secure?

Tags: java, servlets, session-cookies

```
javax.servlet.http.Cookie implements java.lang.Cloneable
```

In Cookie method, there is a method call "setSecure" , what does it use for? if i setSecure(true), is there anything i need to do on my client(javascript) side to read the cookie?   what is different set/without setSecure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All that [`setSecure(true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setSecure(boolean)) does is tell the browser that the cookie should only be sent back to the server if using a "secure" protocol, like `https`. Your JavaScript code doesn't have to do anything different.

Answer (score 3):

Yup this ensures that your session cookie is **not visible to an attacker** like man-in-the-middle attack. Instead of setting it **manually** You could alternatively configure your web.xml to handle it for you **automatically**.

```
<session-config>
   <cookie-config>
      <secure>true</secure>
   </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```